# Consider the set of all ten digit numbers where each digit $0$ to $9$ appears exactly once. If you allow a leading $0$, how many numbers are there?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many numbers are there if you do not allow leading $0$'s?

In how many of the numbers in each case is no digit $j$ in the $j$th place?

If leading $0$'s are allowed?

If they are not allowed?

I know how to answer this if the numbers $0$ through $9$ can be repeated, but I am getting hung up on the "exactly one" part.

Answer (score 2):

Approach via the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)  (*also called the multiplication principle*) which can be paraphrased as the following:

> If you wish to count how many outcomes there are to a particular scenario and you can describe the outcomes via a sequence of steps such that
>
> - **every** outcome is counted **exactly once**
> - Each step has a particular number of options available which do *not* depend on previously made choices in earlier steps
>
> then the total number of outcomes is the product of the number of options at each step.

*Note:* The number of options at each step cannot change based on earlier choices, however *the choices themselves* can change.

---

For your problem:

- Pick the first digit (*It can be any of 0,1,2,3,...,9 in the first problem or it can be any of 1,2,3,...,9 in the second problem*)  How many options is that available for this step?
- Pick the second digit (*It can be any of 0,1,2,3,...,9* **except** *what you picked in the first step.  We wanted each to occur exactly once, not more than once, so whatever you picked is no longer available to pick.*)  How many options is that available for this step?
- Pick the third digit (*It can be any of 0,1,2,3,...,9* **except** *whatever you picked in either of the first two steps*)
- $\vdots$
- Pick the last digit

Multiply the number of options available for each step together to get the total number of arrangements.

Answer (score 0):

10! (10 factorial)

Choose any of the 10 numbers (maybe a 6). 
Then you have 9 numbers to choose for the next digit, and so on.

When you get rid of the leading 0, simply take away the 9! numbers that had a leading 0.

i.e. 10! - 9!